# Using Function.prototype.bind or saved reference

Tags: javascript

This is subjective (opinion based) - but only to a degree, don't rush voting to close. Causing some arguments at work as everyone has a different opinion and people are trying to enforce a single way of doing it.

Simple context: when you have the option to save a reference in your closure to the instance or to use a polyfilled `Function.prototype.bind`, what possible disadvantages do you see to either approach?

To illustrate possible usecases, I just made up some class methods.

Pattern one, saved ref:

```
obj.prototype.addEvents = function(){
    var self = this;

    // reference can be local also - for unbinding. 
    this.onElementClick = function(){
        self.emit('clicked');
        self.element.off('click', self.onElementClick);
    };

    this.element.on('click', this.onElementClick);
};
```

Pattern two, a simple fn.bind:

```
obj.prototype.addEvents = function(){
    // saved reference needs to be bound to this to be unbound
    // once again, this can be a local var also.  
    this.onElementClick = function(){
        this.emit('clicked');
        this.element.off('click', this.onElementClick);
    }.bind(this);

    this.element.on('click', this.onElementClick);
};
```

Pattern two and a half, proto method to event:

```
obj.prototype.addEvents = function(){
    // delegate event to a class method elsewhere 
    this.element.on('click', this.onElementClick.bind(this));
};

obj.prototype.onElementClick = function(){
    this.emit('clicked');
    this.element.off('click', this.onElementClick); // not matching due to memoized bound 
};
```

Personally, I am of the opinion that there isn't a single correct way of doing this and should judge on a per-case basis. I quite like the saved reference pattern where possible. I am being told off.

### Question recap:

Are there any GC issues to be considered / be mindful of?

Are there any other obvious downsides or pitfalls you can think of on either method?

Polyfill performance or event native `.bind` vs a saved ref?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly why this shouldn't be closed. I don't see a practical issue you / your colleagues are actually facing. (As opposed to imagining - if they're worried about GC issues or "polyfill performance", have **them** prove it.) I use saved refs because you can give them more explicit names than `this` which makes for more readable code, which at least is a real advantage.

Comment: `this.onElementClick` even *should* be a local variable, otherwise you might call `addEvents` twice and overwrite the property so that the first bound function is lost.

Answer (score 1):

My personal preference is to use the saved reference method. Reasoning about the value of `this` can be very hard sometimes because of how JavaScript treats `this`.

The bind is nice but if you miss the `.bind(this)` it looks like a bug.

The latter exposes too much; every time you need a callback you'd need to expose another helper in your API.

---

There are many ways to use prototyping. I think the most important thing is to pick one and stick to it.

Comment: I was gonna say same thing - `.bind(this)` makes it easy to mess code and is, supposedly, slower than `self`.

Comment: What does this have to do with prototyping?

Comment: @millimoose if you don't use prototyping, you don't have to use `this`, you don't have to use `bind`. So: everything.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen First: that's not what the word "prototyping" means, you mean "Javascript's prototype-based object system". (Or JS OO.) Second: the issue arises without using it. You need to use one of the two patterns very frequently when using jQuery, and jQuery *barely* uses JS OO - it mostly uses `function.apply()` to rebind `this` in your callbacks. The accurate thing to say would be that you need to save a `this` whenever you're facing the possibility of its value changing, and there's about three ways to do that in Javascript. (Method call, `bind()`, `call()` and `apply()`.)

Comment: My comment was in relation to OPs post. I'll agree that issues with `this` occur even when you're not prototyping. It doesn't detract from the fact that using `this` is a choice. On the other hand, if you _do_ use prototyping (which is the case here) it would be madness not to use `this`. Not everyone believes that jQuery is the be-all-end-all <del>f</del>.

Comment: no jquery here. it's actually dojo classes and dojo.lang.hitch as alternative which is far from performant. irrelevant anyway it's a generic question

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any GC issues to be considered / be mindful of?

Older engines don't infer what variables are still used from the closure and do persist the whole scope. Using `bind` does make it easy because the context is explicitly passed and the un-collected scope does not contain additional variables.

However, this doesn't make a difference if you're using a function expression anyway (as in patterns #1 and #2).

> Are there any other obvious downsides or pitfalls you can think of on either method?

Saving reference:

- needs an additional line for declaring the variable, sometimes even a whole new scope (IEFE)
- Code can't be easily moved because you need to rename your variable

Using bind:

- Easily overlooked on the end of a function expression (just like the invocation of an IEFE), it's not clear what `this` refers to when reading from top to bottom
- Easily forgotten

I personally tend to use bind because of its conciseness, but only with functions (methods) declared elsewhere.

> Polyfill performance or event native .bind vs a saved ref?

You don't care.

---

In your example, you actually don't need that reference to the bound function and the `off` method. jQuery can take care of that itself, you can use the [`one` method](http://api.jquery.com/one/) for binding fire-once listeners. Then your code can be shortened to

```
obj.prototype.addEvents = function(){
    this.element.one('click', this.emit.bind(this, 'clicked'));
};
```

Comment: yeah, fair enough, thanks for the input. no jquery - this was pseudo code, hence the basic example. reality is even if I do have a `:once` pseudo, I may want to unbind events much later. May be listening to events from a data source/socket/emitter or whatever so it's not a DOM centric thing. The point with `.off` was was to illustrate how due to `fn != fn.bind(obj)`, using `bind` can be more awkward for event removals

Comment: Sure, in those cases `bind` will hardly be applicable. The mix of using `bind` for `this` and referring to `boundFn` outside the closure is rather dispisable.